# rtlsdr doesn't open in qt android c++

Tags: android, c++, register-transfer-level

I have a qt android project in c++. When I call "rtlsdr_get_device_name" function it returns the "Generic RTL2832U OEM" message. But when I call "rtlsdr_open" function it return -3. Please help me how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Could you post the code producing the error and the error message that it produces.  And what result you want to see?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thank you silicontrip.
My project is a qt android project.

```
rtlsdr_dev_t *RtlSdrDevice;
int devicecount = rtlsdr_get_device_count();
if (devicecount != 0)
{
    QString rtlname = rtlsdr_get_device_name(0);
    //this function returns "Generic RTL2832U OEM "
    
    retvalue = rtlsdr_open(&RtlSdrDevice, 0);
    //this function returns "-3"
    
    if (retvalue == 0)  //if open rtl correctly
    {
        ....
    }

    ...
}
```

the rtlsdr device doesn't open successfully.